# How to call individual form elements from the fieldset of a child entity in ZF2

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In a view script the syntax to call a form element from a fieldset is something like:

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('member')->get('firstName'));
```

This script calls the single element `firstName` from the fieldset `member`.  However, if the fieldset element refers to an alias for an associative fieldset entity, this script calls all of the elements in the child table.  What is the syntax to call a single element from the child table?

In other words, let’s say we have a `members` entity and a `members` fieldset that include elements like `firstName` and `lastName`.  We also have an `address` entity and an `address` fieldset that include elements like `address`, `city`, `state`, and `zipcode`.  For the ORM associations, the `members` entity includes an `addressInfo` element that establishes the link to the `address` entity, and the `address` entity includes a `memberItem` element that establishes the link back to the `members` entity.  In this case,

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('member')->get('firstName'));
```

produces a single `firstName` form element in the view script, while

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('member')->get(‘addressInfo’));
```

produces form elements for `address`, `city`, `state`, and `zipcode`.

I would assume that if we want to produce a form element only for `city`, the script might want to be something like

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('member')->get(‘addressInfo’)->get(‘city’));
```

or

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('member')->get(‘addressInfo’, ‘city’));
```

but neither of these work.

What is the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `addressInfo` element is a collection, it is necessary to identify which 'row' of the collection before identifying the 'field.'  Therefore,

```
$member           = $form->get('member');
$addressFieldsets = $member->get('addressInfo');
$addressInfo      = $addressFieldsets[0];
$city             = $addressInfo->get('city');

echo $this->formRow($city);
```

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it down, you want the following ...

```
$member      = $form->get('member');
$addressInfo = $member->get('addressInfo');
$city        = $addressInfo->get('city');

echo $this->formRow($city);
```

Chaining the calls together, you end up with this

```
echo $this->formRow($form->get('member')->get('addressInfo')->get('city'));
```

Comment: I thought that would work, but it gives a Zend\Form\Exception\InvalidElementException error: `No element by the name of [city] found in form`